# TypeORM: subscribe to two models

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, typeorm

Hi I have been working with TypeORM and Im having trouble subscribing to two models, actions...
I want to listen to changes on two models not just one

I have 2 models User and Post
How can I listen to update on both of those models

```
import { EntitySubscriberInterface, EventSubscriber, InsertEvent, UpdateEvent } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';

@EventSubscriber()
export class HistorySubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {

    listenTo() {
        return User; // here i would like to listen also to post Updates
    }


    /**
     * Called after User update.
     */
    async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<User>) {
        const newValue = event.entity;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `EntitySubscriberInterface` can only listen to

- exactly one entity or
- to any (all) entities

See the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#what-is-a-subscriber) for an example. If you look at the corresponding [code line](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a3af9e1c62465f00ced109eda0374ca308bbe17a/src/subscriber/Broadcaster.ts#L332) in TypeORM that evaluates `listenTo()`, it should also be possible to filter for a parent class of entity classes.

```ts
subscriber.listenTo().isPrototypeOf(target);
```

So if the `User` and `Post` entity class inherits from the same parent class, it should be possible to subscribe to both classes with one subscriber.